# Javascript v3 API to show map with 2 geolocations

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to display a map that adjusts to the appropriate zoom levels such that 2 specified gelocations are shown on it. For e.g. I would like to show London and Brussels both on the map and I want the zoom to be handled automatically to achieve this. What is the best way to do it?

Thanks,
Yash

Answer (score 0):

The [Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map)-object has a method called fitBounds which does exactly what you are searching for. Just pass a [LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) object and you are done.